# Is there an nginx that isn't an ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, nginx

I'm using traefik as an ingress controller. I'm looking to route traffic to a webserver. Is there a helm chart that packages up nginx not as an ingress controller but as a webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami packages software to helm charts. One of them is Nginx web server.

[Bitnami Nginx Helm Chart from Artifacthub.io](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/nginx) or you can pull it from Bitnami [Official Bitnami Website](https://bitnami.com/stack/nginx/helm)
A quick reference on the Bitnami site to get start

```
helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/nginx
or
helm pull oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/nginx
```

A cool thing about Bitnami is that nginx is running in non privilege port.
Happy Helming !!